# Python's uninstllation caused pip to stop working

Tags: python, pip

I have uninstsalled python 3.6, and just installed 3.7. I have tried using pip on cmd, but when doing so I get this message:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files\python36\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe" '
```

It seems that pip is still referencing the old python version. I know I can use `py -m pip` instead, but I really want to use only pip. Any solutions?

Comment: First, how did you uninstall 3.6? Is it still on your `PATH`? (Also: if you removed it from PATH via the system environment variables control panel, but haven't opened a new command prompt, do that.)

Comment: Meanwhile, which `pip.exe` is getting run? (IIRC, that's `where pip` on Windows.) If 3.6 pip was installed into some system-wide directory that comes earlier on your PATH than the Python 3.7 stuff, you'll need to delete it manually.

Comment: I have deleted some environment variables using python 3.6 that I've created (such as PYTHON_HOME and such) before the uninstallation. I have not deleted it from PATH (forgotten to do so). The problem seems to still occur.

Comment: About your second comment, I'm kind of a newbie, as you can probably tell. How can I spot the location of installation of the 3.6 pip? I tried tracking down the directory, but couldn't.

Comment: As I said in the first place,I think `where pip` is how you get the location of `pip.exe`. Also, given that you didn't read that, let me ask this again as well: After removing 3.6 from your `PATH`, did you start a new command prompt window?

Comment: I have, but not immediately. And using your tip (sorry for not seeing it), I found the exact installation path. So, should I just remove it from there?

Comment: As you mentioned, the result of `where pip` was indeed the location of `pip.exe`. I have deleted its containing directory, and now inputting `pip` outputs the usual: `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

Comment: Added python to the environment variables, and now everything's fine. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the first problem is that the first `pip` on your PATH is one that got left behind by Python 3.6.

You can find it with `where pip`, and it will show you… something named `pip.exe`, in some standard location (like your Windows system directory?) that comes before any of your Python 3.7 directories on the your PATH.

So, find that `pip.exe` and delete it.

Also, make sure you no longer have the Python 3.6 directories on your PATH. (If you change this in the control panel, you will have to open a new Command Prompt window to see the effects.)

Now, either `pip` will just work (with 3.7), or it will tell you `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, instead of trying to work with the missing 3.6 and failing.

---

If you get the "not recognized" error:

Python installers no longer add everything to your PATH by default. Handling Scripts directories from multiple Python installations is a nightmare, especially for novices, and it's easier to recommend everyone use `py -m pip` and `py -m otherscript`.

If you don't like that recommendation, and you're experienced enough to either avoid, or properly deal with, multiple Python installations, you can manually manage your `PATH` to get the old behavior.

The way to do that is pretty simple: just look inside your Python 3.7 directory, see where `pip` is, and add that location to your `PATH`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip + explanation! I think I'll use `py -m pip` from now on, but adding the pip path to `PATH` can also be done through changing the installation through control panel, and marking the 'Create a path' checkbox.

Comment: @ABN263, welcome to stackoverflow. If the answer helped you, please upvote and accept the answer.